# puppet not signing cert or getting new requests

Tags: linux, puppet

I am not sure how to word the question, so here is the problem:

I have a brand new install of puppet-server and puppet using v2.6.16 and running on 2 nodes (puppet and puppet-agent, respectively) following the steps at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/installation.html for a Linux box (CentOS).

On the puppet[-server] box, I issue `puppetca -la` and get back:

```
+ puppet (DB:50:1B:37:47:78:DA:F2:69:28:B7:E2:22:1B:C5:28) (alt names: DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.abc.com)
```

(note that puppet-agent is not listed) ... also, no puppet instances are listed with `puppet cert list`

When signing the box with `puppetca --sign puppet`, I get:

```
err: Could not call sign: Could not find certificate request for puppet
```

Same with `puppetca --sign puppet.abc.com`

There is a puppet.pem in the private_keys and certs directory.  The certificate_requests directory is empty.  Auto-signing is off.

I'd be happy to supply any additional information and would appreciate any assistance.

The puppet.conf on both machines is as follows, sans comments:

```
[main]
  logdir = /var/log/puppet
  rundir = /var/run/puppet
  vardir = /var/lib/puppet
  factpath = $vardir/lib/facter
  ssldir = $vardir/ssl
  server = puppet.abc.com
  dns_alt_names = puppet, puppet.abc.com
  pluginsync = true

[agent]
  classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
  localconfig = $vardir/localconfig

[master]
  templatedir = var/lib/puppet/templates
```

**EDIT DUE TO COMMENTS**

- Master is running
- Agent can contact master via hostname
- Agent CANNOT telnet to 8140 on master -- master is listening on 0.0.0.0:8140 with iptables and selinux off
- May 14 13:40:13 puppet-agent puppet-agent[25920]: (/File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]) Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  May 14 13:40:13 puppet-agent puppet-agent[25920]: (/File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]) Could not evaluate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet.abc.com/plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  May 14 13:40:14 puppet-agent puppet-agent[25920]: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
- puppet agent --test yields: 
  dnsdomainname: Unknown host
  info: Retrieving plugin
  err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet.abc.com/plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  dnsdomainname: Unknown host
  err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
  warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
  err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
  May 14 13:40:14 puppet-agent puppet-agent[25920]: Using cached catalog
- netstat produces ruby/puppet in a LISTEN state and the agent in a TIME_WAIT

Comment: My advice, forget about the puppetca commands. That's old stuff and will just confuse the issue. Modern versions of Puppet, such as the one you're using, do everything via `puppet` subcommands, such as `puppet cert`. See `puppet help` for the list of available commands.

Comment: The certs were out of sync ... issuing the following on the agent resolved the issue: find /var/lib/puppet -type f -print0 |xargs -0r rm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any open signing requests should be listed in `puppet cert list` on the master. If they don't show up there, there's no use trying to sign them. Once signed, they disappear from the list and will only show up in `puppet cert list --all`.

It appears your master is not receiving signing requests from the agent, since your list is empty There is a number of things that could be wrong. Let's start with these:

- Is the master running?
- Does the hostname 'puppet' or 'puppet.abc.com' resolve from the agent?
- Is TCP port 8140 on the master reachable from the agent (try: `telnet puppet 8140`)?
- What does syslog on the agent say?
- Try `puppet agent --test` on the agent, which will attempt to connect to the master and stay in foreground to show the output.

Comment: Adjusted question with results of your comments.  Thanks!

Comment: Resolved the issue with troubleshooting steps above ... giving answer.  Thanks!

Comment: puppet cert is highly depend on DNS (FQDN). So make sure you have proper DNS entry and PTR entry.