# Could not call sign: Could not find certificate request for puppet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, puppet

I'm getting started with puppet on ec2 using the following guide.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html

In the very last step when I try to sign the puppet client from the puppet master I get the following error

```
root@ip-10-248-27-66:/home/ubuntu# puppetca --sign ec2-54-245-56-210.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
err: Could not call sign: Could not find certificate request for ec2-54-245-56-210.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Here is the output of `/etc/hosts` on the puppetmaster

```
127.0.0.1 localhost puppetmaster
10.248.34.162 ec2-54-245-56-210.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com puppet

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Here is the output of `/etc/hosts` on the puppet client

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.248.27.66 ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com puppetmaster

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I followed the troubleshooting advice here https://serverfault.com/a/388973/85577

**Is the master running?**

```
root@ip-10-248-27-66:/home/ubuntu# service puppetmaster status
 * master is running
```

**Does the hostname 'puppet' or 'puppet.abc.com' resolve from the agent?**

How would I check this?  Do I simply telnet to `puppetmaster` on port 8140 (the host command does not resolve it but the telnet command does)?

```
root@ip-10-248-34-162:/home/ubuntu# host puppetmaster
Host puppetmaster not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

**Is TCP port 8140 on the master reachable from the agent (try: telnet puppet 8140)?**

```
root@ip-10-248-34-162:/home/ubuntu# telnet puppetmaster 8140
Trying 10.248.27.66...
Connected to ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**What does syslog on the agent say?**

```
Apr 11 17:57:41 ip-10-248-34-162 puppet-agent[3897]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

**Try puppet agent --test on the agent, which will attempt to connect to the master and stay in foreground to show the output.**

```
root@ip-10-248-34-162:/home/ubuntu# puppet agent --test
err: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

**EDIT**

Thanks dawud so the entries in `/etc/hosts` are correct per this command

```
$ getent hosts puppetmaster
10.248.27.66 ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com puppetmaster
```

however when I try this I get an error

```
$ puppet agent --test --waitforcert 5
err: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)
err: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check that both the puppetmaster and the client machine can resolve the FQDN of the puppetmaster. For this to work, you need to add the puppetmaster IP to your `/etc/hosts` in both machines, then check it using:

`$ ping puppetmaster` or
`$ getent hosts puppetmaster`

Check that you can reach the puppetmaster from the client machine

`$ telnet puppetmaster 8140`

If you get connection refused by the server, check that the port is opened in the puppetmaster

`# iptables -L -n -v`

Or add a rule to allow incoming traffic to that port (this is dependent on how is `iptables` already configured)

`# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8140 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

And run from the client

`# puppet agent --test --waitforcert 5`

Afterwards, from the puppetmaster

`# puppet cert list`

will show you the cert ready to be sign, you can check it belongs to the client machine comparing the fingerprint. Sign it:

`# puppet cert sign $client`

Puppetmaster will compile a catalog for the client and you can follow how it is applied in the client console.

To regenerate the certificates on the puppetmaster, stop the ppuppetmaster and

`# find $(puppet master --configprint ssldir) -name "$(puppet master --configprint certname).pem" -delete`

When you start the puppetmaster again, it will regenerate the certificate for you.

On the client side, it is enough to remove the conttents of the ssldir, usually `/var/lib/puppet/ssl`, but check as above, the next time you invoke

`# puppet agent --test --waitforcert 5`

it will be recreated.

Eventually, check the CN of the certificate of the puppetmaster with

`# puppet cert list --all`

and match any of the names/ALT names to the entry in your /etc/hosts.

Comment: Thanks dawud, I added the puppetmaster into `/etc/hosts` on both machines like so `10.248.27.66 ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com puppetmaster` but `dig puppetmaster` does not resolve.  Only `dig ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` resolves.  Also I'm getting a syntax error on `# puppet agent --test --waitforcert`.  Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: I have corrected the syntax of the command, also, try `ping` or `getent` to resolve the puppetmaster address

Comment: Thanks dawud, I'm still getting an error, can you see my edit (I added the error messages to the bottom of my original question)?  Could it a private key signing issue?

Comment: New edit, please check

Comment: I can telnet on port 8140  into the puppet master from the client and resolve using getent (see original post).  However I am still getting the same exact error `err: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)` when running `$ puppet agent --test --waitforcert 5`.  Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: I have added some simple steps to recreate the certs in both sides

Comment: Thanks again.  So here's where I am stuck.  I stopped the puppet master, regenerated the certs and started it again but when I run `puppet cert list` nothing comes up.  I'm confused about the whole certificate issue.  I spun up 2 fresh ec2 instances.  Am I supposed to upload the `.pem` files to each of them?  Where do I put them and how do I initialize them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8303/discussion-between-dawud-and-user784637)

Comment: hey there.  I just wanted to follow up and mention that I think the problem was in fact with the configuration of the `/etc/hosts` file (not quite sure what I did wrong, I tripled checked everything).  by default `puppet agent` uses `puppet` as the default argument to `--server` but I didn't experience any problems when I explicitly set the `--server` argument to the FQDN of my puppetmaster.

Answer (score 1):

One of things noted in discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/rSE6iwDWyZA) and not mentioned in previous is answer is that sometimes ports can behave strangely. In my case inspite of having the port 8140 opened in iptables, I was getting errors of not being able to connect. What helped me is following commands:

```
iptables -F
service service iptables save
```

Of course use `sudo` if above command fail with your user. I even added the above two commands in the provisionoing script of the box so that if I halt/recreate the boxes - the iptables is flushed.

Comment: The above answer seems to be correct if you have a network issue and not issue related to puppet installation and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues and resolved it with some different tweaks.

Same error:

```
[root@puppetclient puppet]# puppet agent --server yogesh.puppet.com
--no-daemonize --verbose Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2) for "yogesh.puppet.com" port 8140 Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2) for "yogesh.puppet.com" port 8140 Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2) for "yogesh.puppet.com" port 8140 Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2) for "yogesh.puppet.com" port 8140
```

I tried every thing Iptables, ports, firewalls, agent-reinstallation (not master). Then I started to look more and found something in the log files as:

```
I, [2016-04-27T23:21:55.118997 #1745]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:139:in `on_ssl_connecting' Establishing SSL session with stomp+ssl://mcollective@yogesh.puppet.com:61613
E, [2016-04-27T23:21:55.131678 #1745] ERROR -- : activemq.rb:149:in `on_ssl_connectfail' SSL session creation with stomp+ssl://mcollective@yogesh.puppet.com:61613 failed: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch
I, [2016-04-27T23:21:55.132438 #1745]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:129:in `on_connectfail' TCP Connection to stomp+ssl://mcollective@yogesh.puppet.com:61613 failed on attempt 36
I, [2016-04-27T23:22:25.141892 #1745]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:139:in `on_ssl_connecting' Establishing SSL session with stomp+ssl://mcollective@yogesh.puppet.com:61613
E, [2016-04-27T23:22:25.144644 #1745] ERROR -- : activemq.rb:149:in `on_ssl_connectfail' SSL session creation with stomp+ssl://mcollective@yogesh.puppet.com:61613 failed: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch
I, [2016-04-27T23:22:25.144836 #1745]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:129:in `on_connectfail' TCP Connection to stomp+ssl://mcollective@yogesh.puppet.com:61613 failed on attempt 37
```

This gave me the indication of certificates present on Master server. I re-created the master key and it worked for me.

Caution: This was the only testing environments for me, dont play with it directly on production environments.

```
[root@YogeshRaheja init.d]# puppet cert clean "yogesh.puppet.com"
Notice: Revoked certificate with serial 11
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::Certificate yogesh.puppet.com at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/signed/yogesh.puppet.com.pem'
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::Certificate yogesh.puppet.com at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/yogesh.puppet.com.pem'
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest yogesh.puppet.com at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests/yogesh.puppet.com.pem'
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::Key yogesh.puppet.com at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/yogesh.puppet.com.pem'


[root@YogeshRaheja init.d]# puppet cert generate yogesh.puppet.com
Notice: yogesh.puppet.com has a waiting certificate request
Notice: Signed certificate request for yogesh.puppet.com
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest yogesh.puppet.com at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/yogesh.puppet.com.pem'
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest yogesh.puppet.com at '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests/yogesh.puppet.com.pem'


[root@YogeshRaheja init.d]# ./pe-puppetserver start
Starting pe-puppetserver:                                  [  OK  ]
[root@YogeshRaheja init.d]#
[root@YogeshRaheja init.d]#
[root@YogeshRaheja init.d]# netstat -an | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::4433                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::8081                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::5432                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::42632                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::8140                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::61613                    :::*                        LISTEN
```

and it resolved the client connection issue.